# randomly overwritten object members

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault

This is my first question at stackoverflow, after I've been using it quite a lot passively.

My question is actually very specific, but I try to be as general as possible: I have written a program to simulate the time evolution of quantum physics wave function. For this I use the [itensor libraries](http://itensor.org), which basically performs linear algebra operation on large tensors (something like a matrix with not two but several indices), which make the tensors grow in time in a controlled way, i.e. there is an upper limit for tensor sizes. These simulations need typically a few days of runtime and a lot of memory. Now I got a more or less random segmentation fault after a few hours. Random means, that it can not be reproduced with the same simulation parameters at the same time, but occurs nevertheless every once in a while.

When taking a look at the tensor object at the moment it crashes, I can see, that some of its members (Indices) are wrongly overwritten with defaultly created ones, which causes errors later. So some of the object members seem to be deleted during runtime and then later newly created. I am not an expert on that, but the randomness and the long time until it occurs make it looks to me, as if there is some problem with the memory during runtime. I pass all large objects by reference and define them explicitly on the heap, to minimize the use of stack memory by

```
MPSt<IQTensor> *psi = new IQMPS(psi0);
compute_quantum_trajectory(...,*psi,...);
delete psi;
```

but this did not help. Is there a way the object's properties can be influenced/deleted by some other parts of the porgram, and how can I track such behavior? 
here a sketch of the problematic part of the program:

```
MPSt<IQTensor> *psi = new IQMPS(psi0);
compute_quantum_trajectory(...,*psi,...);
delete psi;

void compute_quantum_trajectory(...,MPSt<IQTensor> &psi,... )
{

  for(int step = nstart; step < nfinal; ++step)
  {
    do_some_tensor_operation(psi,...); 
  }
}

void do_some_tensor_operation(MPSt<IQTensor> &psi)
{
  // do some valid non-constant operation on psi
  // program crashes sometimes, because Index of psi is overwritten 
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Stefan

Comment: This would be a great example to run in a debugger (such as GDB) if you can recreate it often. This will allow you to view your current state and why it is seg faulting.

Comment: "Is there a way the object's properties can be influenced/deleted by some other parts of the program..." - certainly, but highly likely not *intentionally*. If your program invokes *undefined behavior* it is entirely conceivable what you're witnessing can happen (or not). I'd at least turn valgrind and/or a debugger loose on this. if you're fortunate, they can identify where you're breaching some unhonored limit, even when you *don't* witness your crash. I'm afraid without real, *complete* code and data that produces your crash, there isn't much we'll be able to help you with.

Comment: Tthose are probably to trivial issues and I guess you have checked them, but sometimes it is the most difficult to find the most obvious troubles, so I put some questions. Maybe you can use `try{...}catch(std::bad_alloc&){}`. How much the tensor can grow? Is it possible you exceed one of the limits(like as `int` limit). Do you have precompiled part of the code where you possibly could changed members of a class? Try to rebuild all sources.

Comment: Thanks for the help & sorry for the late reply, this error is not easy to debug, because of the late times it occurs. I created core dumps and could backtrace the error to one of the library functions. I also did some runs with valgrind but there the error didn't came along so far, maybe because valgrind slows down the  program significantly. I think it is probable, that the error is caused somewhere in the library. I am in contact with the developers. The growing of the tensor is very controlled, it actually is part of the algorithm to cut it off to a given size. thanks anyways for the input.